# Apache Ignite ODBC and ADODB Recordset problem fetching data

Tags: odbc, ignite, adodb

i try to fetch records from Apache Ignite inmemory database via Microsoft Access 2016 32-Bit and Apache Ignite 32-Bit ODBC-driver with default settings. OS is Windows 10.
Import as a linked table does not work so i tried via ADODB-Class.
Connection.Open and Recordset.Open works and i can see all columns (ID and NAME) of sample table CITY in the Recordset. But when i try to fetch the first record with MoveFirst or MoveNext, i get the error 'specified attribute is not supported'. I tried the same with CursorLocation=adUseClient and the error message changes to 'wrong parameter'. Default Provider is MSDASQL.1. Is this the correct Provider? Any idea how to fetch records with ADODB?

Code

`
Public Sub QueryIgnite()

```
Dim ADOrs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ADOcon As ADODB.Connection

Set ADOcon = New ADODB.Connection
ADOcon.ConnectionString = "DSN=Apache-Ignite-DSN"
'ADOcon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
ADOcon.Open
Set ADOrs = New ADODB.Recordset
ADOrs.Open "select * from city", ADOcon, adOpenForwardOnly
ADOrs.MoveNext
Debug.Print ADOrs.Fields("NAME")
ADOrs.Close
ADOcon.Close
End Sub
```

`
Thank you in advance.
Regards.
Guido Clesius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ticket on apache.org is created to fix the bug. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-18210